# Replace part of Sequence with another Sequence at Index

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Is there an easy way to replace part of a sequence with another one at a specified position?

```
(def s1 '(1 2 3 4 5 6))
(def s2 '(:a :b :c))
(insert s1 s2 2)

; => (1 2 :a :b :c 6)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is:

```
(defn insert [a b idx]
  (let [h (take idx a)
        t (drop (+ idx (count b)) a)]
    (concat h b t)))
```